# Horizontal line between first and second bootstrap rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap rows to make 3 columns with buttons but when I make them, it showing a horizontal line that separates first column from second one. The problem is that I don`t want that line there and it only shows between first column and second one.

How can I take that annoying line off ?

Here is my code and a photo:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1">  
            <h5>Noise pollution</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">  
            <h5>Waste pollution</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">  
            <h5>Chimic pollution</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

I don't have any css for this, only css offered by bootstrap and it shows that line there :(.

Comment: Post your CSS too

Comment: can you please share a demo link showing your problem. I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the code you have mentioned

Comment: I'm using only bootstrap CSS code. The code is working fine, but the CSS from bootstrap seems to insert a horizontal line there and I don`t have ideea how to take it off.

Comment: There is something in your css codes that is causing a container to inherit a style with that line..I am pretty sure.....have you tried running the codes in your question and see how it looks? there is no line!...hence we'd appreciate if you post your css or even your entire codes (in a fiddle or pen)

Comment: Problem solved. That line was a border from CSS bootstrap and seems that my code inherits it. I overwrited the borders and it worked.

Comment: be careful now setting border:none to all elements within the same class can spoil your layout becuase some elements that needs that border will suffer.....I would suggest to add an id and style

Comment: It's ok, i don't need border for any of row classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the CSS which applies this styling in the inspector of the developer tool. Still, if you are unable to locate you can overwrite the CSS to remove borders. Try adding below code snippet at the end of your CSS file,

```
.container-fluid .row .col-sm-1 {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)